# Different OP in CMD Prompt & Sublime Buid

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, assert

i have written a code to assert in below code:

```
def KelvinToFahrenheit(Temperature):
    assert (Temperature >= 0),"Colder than absolute zero!"
    return ((Temperature-273)*1.8)+32

print (KelvinToFahrenheit(273))
print (int(KelvinToFahrenheit(505.78)))
print (KelvinToFahrenheit(-5))
```

when i ran(windows 10, python 3.6.1) the above code using command prompt : assertion is working properly.

```
O/P :
32.0
451

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "assert.py", line 8, in <module>
print (KelvinToFahrenheit(-5))
File "assert.py", line 2, in KelvinToFahrenheit
assert (Temperature >= 0),"Colder than absolute zero!"
AssertionError: Colder than absolute zero!
```

But when i run using sublime O/P -

```
32.0 
451
-468.40000000000003
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

someone guide me please

Comment: Check If it is the same code that you are run in same scenarios. If it is so, can you update your answer including the shell_cmd output of Sublime console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried and I got the same assertion error as it is supposed to.
You might be running a different version.
python shell and python idle would be in different version.

Comment: i double checked both editor are using same version of python.

Sublime OP:`32.0
451
-468.40000000000003
3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[Finished in 0.1s]`


Pycharm : 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" PycharmProjects/ppp/loop.py
3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]<br/> 

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are using PyCharm not Sublime. I never work with PyCharm but your problem should be that you are running "PycharmProjects/ppp/loop.py" project with an configuration that turns on [PYTHONOPTIMIZE](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONOPTIMIZE) environment variable. This mode turns any assert statement into a null operation and wont be evaluated.

You should check run/debug configurations in your IDE.